# Passing variables as filepath to io.popen() fail+ [LUA]

Tags: lua

I have file paths in a table and looping thru it I'm trying to pass those paths to io.popen() in a variable, but it looks like I'm failing to, type the io.popen() arguments.

What I have so far:

fho4 = assert(io.open(directory4,"w+"))

```
    if #filePath2 > 0 then  
        for dir1 in io.popen("dir" ..filePath2[i].. "/b"):lines() do table.insert(h, dir1) end  
            
    if #h > 0 then 
        for i = 1,#h,1 do
            counter = counter+1
            if counter >= #h+1 then break end
            fho4:write(h[i] .."\n") 
        end
    end
    end --#filePath2
    
                fho4:close()
```

I must add that **filePath2** contains just directory paths, so I try to pass each one to io.popen()  in order to get the files each directory has and store them in a table (h), to list them in a text file (directory4) for later use.
When I run the script as is, it throws an error message: filePath2[i] is a nil value, and **#filePath2 = 0**, if I comment the io.popen line and run the script, then **#filePath2 = 6** (the right value), of course, no nil error.
I've noticed in every example I saw, that people pass the file paths as a string to io.popen, rather than a variable, so ignore if it is possible to do so.

Most like this work:

```
for dir1 in io.popen("dir c:\Mydir\myfile.txt.. /b"):lines() do table.insert(h, dir1)   end
```

But I dunno what the filename is, so I can't use strings, just a variable storing the path files.

What am I missing here?

---

```
    if #filePath3 > 0 then
    fho1 = assert(io.open(directory4,"w+"))

    for i = 1,#filePath3,1 do
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter >= #filePath3+1 then break end
        fho1:write(filePath3[i] .."\n") 
        
        if not filePath3[i]:match("^.+(%..+)$") then -- ext
            table.insert(filePath2,filePath3[i])
        end 
        
    end
end --#filePath3
    fho1:close()

PromptDuration(#h .." - " ..#filePath2,3000)    
            
if #filePath2 > 0 then
if filePath2[i] ~= nil then

for i = 1,#filePath2,1 do
    for dir1 in io.popen([["dir"..filePath2[i].."/b"]]):lines() do table.insert(h, dir1) end    
end

if #h > 0 then 
    fho4 = assert(io.open(directory4,"a+"))
    
    for i = 1,#h,1 do
        counter = counter+1
        if counter >= #h+1 then break end
        fho4:write(h[i] .."\n") 
    end
    fho4:close()
end
else
return
end
end --#filePath2
```

That script has to do with a game engine so uses many LUA commands that just have to do with the game engine itself, although, allows to use of almost the whole LUA, but just the standard one.

**filePath3** is a table, that contains file paths, some of them point to a media files (audio, images, videos, etc), but some of them point to directories; so, I should filter those file paths to know who are files and who are directories, in the file cases I'll just copy files, i.e: c:\mydir1\mydir2\myfile.ogg, and in the directories case, have to open the directorie, and scan for media files, and then, list all those file paths into a text file (directory4) for later use.
**filePath2** is a table as well, and contains the directories paths, i.e: c:\mydir1\mydir2, so iterating thru filePath2 using io.popen I want to get the list of files these directies contain, listed in a text file (directory4 as well)

As you can see I can't to use strings as arg in io.popen, but a variable that contain the path (filePath2[i]).

Thanks for help me :)

Comment: The sample code does not contain definition of `filePath2` which is important (or `h`; try making it complete and reproduce the issue you are encountering). Note that `"dir" ..filePath2[i].. "/b"` does not separate the command, path and option with whitespace; they are merged together into `"dir<path>/b"`.

Comment: Sorry guys, not familiar with tags use, and I don't see the "edit" tag.

Comment: `[["dir"..filePath2[i].."/b"]` seems even weirder. Did you try fixing lack of spaces I mentioned in previous comment? Something like: `io.popen("dir "..filepath2[i].." /b")` (note the spaces **inside** the quotes after `dir` and before `/b`.)

Comment: I tried:
for i = 1,#filePath2,1 do
 for dir1 in io.popen("dir "..filepath2[i].." /b"):lines() do table.insert(h, dir1) end 
but (h) keep being equal to 0, it means it is doing anything, though
  end

Answer (score 0):

\I've got it using:

```
for dir1 in io.popen("dir "  ..filePath2[i] .." /b"):lines() do   table.insert(h, dir1) end
```

The issue was **filePath2[i]** using a double backslash rather than a simple one, once fixed it works ok.